# F# - specific agile tools

Tags: unit-testing, f#, agile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [F# development and unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989487/f-development-and-unit-testing)

Are there any F# - specific agile software development tools?  I'm thinking of things like a unit testing framework.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468772/how-to-handle-unit-tests-in-f

Answer (score 3):

For unit testing [FSUnit](http://code.google.com/p/fsunit/) exists.

But as a .NET language most .NET tools will work.

Answer (score 2):

For unit testing [FsCheck](http://fscheck.codeplex.com/) the F# port of the Haskell framework QuickCheck is very nice. Basically it generates random tests based a specification of what the function does.