# Comparing Discriminated Unions

Tags: f#, discriminated-union, fsunit

I'm a newbie to F# and I'm playing around with FParsec.  I would use FParsec to generate an AST.  I would like to use FsUnit to write some tests around the various parts of the parser to ensure correct operation.

I'm having a bit of trouble with the syntax (sorry, the exact code is at work, I can post a specific example later) so how exactly could one compare two discriminated unions (one the expected, the other the actual result)?  Could someone provide a tiny code example using FsUnit (or NUnit), please?

An example discriminated union (very simple)

```
type AST = 
    | Variable of string
    | Class of string
    | Number of int
```

Comment: (F# unions have structural equality, which means that `=` does the right thing, comparing the entire structure/value.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since, as Brian pointed out, F# unions have structural equality, this is easy using whichever unit testing framework you are fond of.

FsUnit is an F# specific library built on top of NUnit. My personal favorite F# specific unit testing library is [Unquote](http://code.google.com/p/unquote/), ;), which is framework agnostic, working very well with NUnit, xUnit.net, MbUnit, ... or even within FSI. You may be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667372/what-unit-testing-frameworks-are-available-for-f/5669263#5669263) comparison with FsUnit.

So, how would you do this with NUnit + Unquote? Here's a full working example:

```
module UnitTests

open NUnit.Framework
open Swensen.Unquote

type AST = 
    | Variable of string
    | Class of string
    | Number of int

let mockFParsec_parseVariable input = Variable(input)

[<Test>]
let ``test variable parse, passing example`` () =
    test <@ mockFParsec_parseVariable "x" = Variable("x") @>

[<Test>]
let ``test variable parse, failing example`` () =
    test <@ mockFParsec_parseVariable "y" = Variable("x") @>
```

Then running the tests using TestDriven.NET, the output is as follows:

```
------ Test started: Assembly: xxx.exe ------

Test 'UnitTests.test variable parse, failing example' failed: 

UnitTests.mockFParsec_parseVariable "y" = Variable("x")
Variable "y" = Variable("x")
false
    C:\xxx\UnitTests.fs(19,0): at UnitTests.test variable parse, failing example()

1 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 0.80 seconds (NUnit 2.5.10).
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try when I get to work.  I think I know what I was doing wrong now after seeing your example.  I was using (Variable "VAR"), but should have been using Variable("VAR") as my expected ... will mark as answered shortly hopefully!

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks.  I'm going to give unquote a hard look because FsUnit just isn't working for me here ...

Comment: Unquote is great, loving it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

An example - if you want to check the type but not the contents

```
let matched x= 
    match x with
    |Variable(_) -> true
    | _ -> false
```

Note here that you need a different function for each element of the discriminated union

If you want to compare equality, you can just do it in the standard way, like

```
Assert.AreEqual(Variable("hello"),result)
```

or

```
if result = Variable("hello") then stuff()
```