# Is there a way to rewrite the when clause in this match statement, in F#

Tags: f#

I have a 'sub state':

```
type SubState =
    | DoingA
    | DoingB
    | AFewMore
```

and a main state:

```
type State =
    | Initializing
    | DoingStuff of SubState
    | DoingNothing
```

and then I use that state in a match statement:

```
let state : State = ... 

match anotherState with
| hello -> ()
| hello when state = Initializing -> ()
| hello when state = DoingStuff -> ()   <- won't compile
| hello when state = DoingStuff _-> ()  <- won't compile either
```

so I have to add to my State a helper:

```
type State =
    | Initializing
    | DoingStuff of SubState
    | DoingNothing

    member this.IsDoingStuff =
        match this with
        | DoingStuff _ -> true
        | _ -> false
```

and then I can do my main match with:

```
match anotherState with
| hello -> ()
| hello when state = Initializing -> ()
| hello when state.IsDoingStuff -> () <- this works
```

but I would really like

```
| hello when state = DoingStuffAndIDontCareAboutTheSubState -> ()
```

Is there a nice syntactic way to the when condition and ignore the value of 'DoingStuff'?

I understand I could do:

```
match anotherState, state with
| hello, DoingStuff _ ->
```

but in many cases, I don't need the second value, so I'm trying to find a solution where I can keep the when statement.

Comment: What's `someStuff` and why are you matching on it?

Comment: sorry, it should read 'anotherState', I'll edit the question

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001567/how-to-check-the-case-of-a-discriminated-union-with-fsunit

Comment: It's still not clear to me why the code is matching on `anotherState`, as it doesn't look like it's doing anything with it. To elaborate, with an unconditional match on a symbol like `hello`, that case is going to match *all* cases, and the subsequent cases will never be hit... if I understand the code correctly.

Comment: I guess my example is a bit too short, there is more than 'hello'; I wanted to illustrate that I've a match on a value and, in some cases a set of conditions but one of them is to match with another state. However I can't do "when state = DoingStuff _", I would have to enumerate all here, or make a helper method

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use [match expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/match-expressions). You can use the normal [identifier pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching#identifier-patterns) here:

```
let state anotherState =
    match anotherState with
    | Initializing -> ()
    | DoingStuff _ -> ()
    | DoingNothing ->
```

You can also nest these and check on the substate:

```
let state anotherState =
        match anotherState with
        | Initializing -> ()
        | DoingStuff DoingA -> ()
        | DoingStuff DoingB -> ()
        | DoingStuff AFewMore -> ()
        | DoingNothing ->
```

Match expressions are useful if you want to work with an expression inside your match case, e.g. suppose that you would have this:

```
type Foo =
   | Bar
   | Baz of int

let state foo =
   match foo with
   | Bar -> ()
   | Baz 0 -> ()
   | Baz 1 -> ()
   | Baz i when i < 10 -> ()
   | Baz _ -> ()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `when` for something you should be using pattern matching for; your last example is the idiomatic way to do this:

```fs
match anotherState, state with
| hello, DoingStuff _ ->
```

`when` is for situations where you can't do this and significantly hurts the compiler's ability to do exhaustiveness checking.

This is all assuming that you're also pattern matching on `anotherState` in your actual code, otherwise that doesn't need to be part of the `match`.