# Why does F# using Xunit require type information when Asserting equality on Strings

Tags: f#, xunit

I'm using F# and Xunit. (I'm relatively new to both)

I've found that when I use Xunit's Assert.Equal() I need to specify `"<string>"` when the types being compared are string.

For example this run's and compiles:

```
[<Fact>]
let Test_XunitStringAssertion() =
    let s1 = "Stuff"
    Assert.Equal<string>("Stuff",s1)
```

My question is, why can't I remove `"<string>"` and just assert `"Assert.Equal("Stuff",s1)"` instead?

It looks to me like the compiler knows the types of both arguments, so why the fuss?

Here are the errors returned when compiling `Assert.Equal("Stuff",s1)`:

```
error FS0041: A unique overload for method 'Equal' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. The available overloads are shown below (or in the Error List window). A type annotation may be needed.
error FS0041: Possible overload: 'Assert.Equal<'T>(expected: 'T, actual: 'T) : unit'.
error FS0041: Possible overload: 'Assert.Equal<'T>(expected: seq<'T>, actual: seq<'T>) : unit'.
error FS0041: Possible overload: 'Assert.Equal<'T>(expected: 'T, actual: 'T, comparer: System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<'T>) : unit'.
error FS0041: Possible overload: 'Assert.Equal(expected: float, actual: float, precision: int) : unit'.
error FS0041: Possible overload: 'Assert.Equal(expected: decimal, actual: decimal, precision: int) : unit'.
error FS0041: Possible overload: 'Assert.Equal<'T>(expected: seq<'T>, actual: seq<'T>, comparer: System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<'T>) : unit'.
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667372/what-unit-testing-frameworks-are-available-for-f/5669263#5669263 (i.e. idiomatic F# assertions that are dramatically underpublicised)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `string` can be matched by both the first and **second** overloads (remember: `string :> seq<char>`).

Answer (score 4):

Your example with `<string>` removed runs without error for me as I'd expect (although `string :> seq<char>` as @Ramon Snir points out, the overload resolution algorithm resolves the ambiguity by recognizing that the supplied `string` types are "closer" to `string` than `seq<char>`).

```
[<Fact>]
let Test_XunitStringAssertion() =
    let s1 = "Stuff"
    Assert.Equal("Stuff",s1)
```

I guess the sample you provided is not exactly the same as the real code which is causing you problems. Maybe `s1` in your real code is not actually a `string` (or at least the compiler doesn't know it is).