# How to compare individual values in f# matrices?

Tags: matrix, f#, f#-powerpack

I am trying to teach myself f#.
For a program I am working on, I want to compare individual elements of 2 matrices, point wise.
The matrices are both of size 1*N. The reason these are matrices is because they are the result of previous computations, performed using the standard F# PowerPack. I am happy to convert them to some other collection after these computations or use some other Matrix math library.
What I need is a function that takes 2 matrices (which are essentially vectors) and outputs a List of index positions where the 2 vectors are not equal.

For example:
Input: [[5;6;7;8;9]]; [[3;6;3;8;3]]
Output: [1;3;5]

My brain still thinks very much in the imperative style and I haven't quite got my head around pattern matching yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Powerpack you can do this:

```
let getDifferences x y = 
    Matrix.Generic.foldi (fun _ j s e -> if e = 0 then s else (j+1)::s) [] (x-y)
    |> List.rev // if you care about the order
```

By looking at your sample arrays I assume your matrices `x` and `y` are Generic matrices of type `int`.

If this is not the case, remove `.Generic` and change `0` for `0.0` but be aware that [comparing floats for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142410/f-assert-areequals-fails-with-two-literals/26146120#26146120) might be not a good idea, depending on your specific scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This would work for two lists:

```
List.zip list1 list2
|> List.mapi (fun i x -> i, x)
|> List.choose (fun (i, (a, b)) -> 
    if a = b then None else Some i)
```

Note, the returned indices are zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you could extract these vectors as collections you could write (it will work without throwing exceptions if vectors have different size):

```
let res' = ([5;6;7;8;9], [3;6;3;8;3]) 
           ||> Seq.zip 
           |> Seq.mapi (fun i (a, b) -> if a = b then None else Some (i + 1)) 
           |> Seq.choose id
```

I added 1 because index in mapi function is 0-based

If you can extract vectors as lists and vectors are always of the same size you can use list functions and save one line not using List.zip:

```
let res'' = ([5;6;7;8;9], [3;6;3;8;3]) 
           ||> List.mapi2 (fun i a b -> if a = b then None else Some (i + 1)) 
           |> List.choose id
```