# How to compare Matrix elements in Math.Net numerics in F#

Tags: matrix, f#, mathnet-numerics

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450301/how-to-compare-individual-values-in-f-matrices/27457194#27457194), I asked how to perform a similar operation using PowerPack.
I have decided to use MathNet instead as it is designed for .Net in general, not just F#.

I need a function that takes 2 matrices and outputs the percentage of agreement. The values in the matrices are all either 1.0 or -1.0. Apparently matrices of type Matrix(int) are not supported.

I have come up with a function that accomplishes this but I suspect there is a more direct route to do this, preferably using functionality of the Matrix class.

This is what I've got:

```
let percentageTheSame (a:Matrix<float>) (b:Matrix<float>) =
  let seqA = a |> Matrix.toSeq
  let seqB = b |> Matrix.toSeq
  let sames = Seq.map2 (fun a b -> (a,b)) seqA seqB |> Seq.filter (fun (a, b) -> a = b)
  float(sames.Count())/float(seqA.Count())
```

Comment: And why is what you have not good enough?

Comment: Only obvious improvement is to use `Seq.zip` instead of the `map2`

Comment: Mine is not good enough because it has to resort to using a non Matrix collection class. Gustavo nailed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution similar to the one using PowerPack:

```
let percentageTheSame (a:Matrix<float>) (b:Matrix<float>) =
  let z,t = Matrix.fold (fun (z,t) e -> (if e = 0. then z+1 else z), t+1) (0,0) (a-b)
  float z / float t
```

Or using `foldi`, instead of subtracting matrices, might be more efficient for big matrices since it doesn't need to allocate an intermediate matrix:

```
let percentageTheSame (a:Matrix<float>) (b:Matrix<float>) =
  let z,t = 
    Matrix.foldi (fun i j (z,t) e -> (if e = b.[i,j] then z+1 else z), t+1) (0,0) a
  float z / float t
```

Comment: Interestingly, there does not appear to be any documentation on the foldi function for the matrix class: http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra/Matrix%601.htm

Comment: May be it's only in the F# component of the MathNet.